# Use placeholders to search in postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql

I want to search in a table for title containing a substring (in my case the substring is the title passed to the `getBookForTitle` method). The problem is that it doesn't return anything.

```
public void getBookForTitle(String title) {
            PreparedStatement stm = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
                stm = connection.prepareStatement("Select * from books where name like '%?%'; ");
                rs = stm.executeQuery();
                while (rs.next()) {
                    System.out.print(rs.getInt(1));
                    System.out.print(": ");
                    System.out.print(rs.getString(1));
                    System.out.println(rs.getBoolean(3));
                }
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never bind a value to your placeholder. Also the placeholder should not contain the % sign and the single quotes.

It must look like:

```
stm = connection.prepareStatement("Select * from books where name like ? ");
stm.setString(1,"%"+your_string+"%")
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed to supply the value for the prepared statement parameter:

```
stm = connection.prepareStatement("Select * from books where name like ? ");
stm.setString(1,"%" + lookup + "%")
rs = stm.executeQuery();
```

Please note that the % character should be set while binding the parameter, not in the statement itself.

Please refer to: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html#supply_values_ps